# Eclipse ADT SAP system connection source

Tags: eclipse, abap-adt

when I create a new ABAP project in Eclipse ADT, Eclipse showing a popup with all known SAP system connections.

Can anyone tell me from which source Eclipse ADT retrieves these connection information?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually System connections are retrieved from the configuration of the installed SAP GUI

##### SAP GUI configuration

You can check in SAP GUI where the configuration is stored:
Options -> SAP Logon Options -> Configuration Files

Look for files: **SAPLogon.ini** / **SAPUILandscape.xml**

By default they are stored in: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common\

##### Eclipse configuration

Environment variable **SAPLOGON_INI_FILE** to specify an alternative location of the saplogon.ini

LandscapeXML alternative path: Window -> Preferences -> ABAP Development -> System Connections